# Detect if website was visited directly..is it possible?

Tags: javascript, php, html

It is possible to detect if my website was visited directly (by user typing in the address as the URL) or if they have visited it by a link they found elsewhere or by a google search result link?  Is this even possible?

Comment: The *Referrer* : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer (Available in PHP also)

Comment: @AlexK. thank you Alex, this is correct, however william.taylor.09 responded just a fraction quicker to to be fair I've checked his as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
document.referrer
```

which returns 'A String, representing the URL of the document that loaded the current document. Returns the entire URL, including the protocol (like http://). If the current document was not opened through a link (for example, through a bookmark), an empty string is returned.'